# Redshift table lock

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to load Redshift table from stage table.

Whenever I try to insert data from the `stage` table, Redshift is locking `table2` and it is not inserting any data.

Here is the python code:

```py
insertSQL = "insert into table2 select c1,c2,c3,c4 FROM table_name "
load_redshift_table(insertSQL)

def load_redshift_table(insertSQL):
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host="host",port="redshift_port",database="redshift_database",user="redshift_user",password="reshift_password")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(insertSQL)
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
    finally:
        cur.close()
```

Comment: Is this really your code? The function needs to be defined before it is called, so running the above code results in `NameError: name 'load_redshift_table' is not defined`.

Comment: A few things to tease apart - "Redshift is locking table2" is this saying that the insert is locking the table or that a pre-existing lock is blocking the insert?  How are you detecting this condition?  You also say Redshift "is not inserting any data": is there an error or hanging or completes fine?  Can you provide some clarity on these points and provide any error messages and results of any debug steps performed so far?

Comment: @BillWeiner,Thank you for your reply.

Comment: pre-existing lock is blocking the insert?
I have created a table and tried loading it from another table using python.How are you detecting this condition? 
There is no progress in load and no response when I query the table I am loading.
You also say Redshift "is not inserting any data": is there an error or hanging or completes fine? 
job is hanging, and no progress.Finally terminated the load process using select pg_terminate_backend(<pid>)I ran a query to find a lock on the table.

Comment: So this seems to indicate a pre-existing lock.  The catalog table pg_locks is where to find these but it is a little hard to get what you need from it.  The good news that there are helpful queries in github made by awslabs.  Check out - https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_get_blocking_locks.sql - you can just run the query inside the view definition if you don't want to create the view on your cluster.

Comment: Thank you Bill.Every time the AcessShareLock happens on the FROM table and insert table. I would like to know why it is happening. One more observation is I can insert the data using the same SQL from editor. But the issue is when I ran the python code AcessShareLock happening.